# Unir dos sumas SQL en una única consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero unir estas dos consultas en una única y sumar los dos resultados:

```
SELECT torneo_organizacion, jugador_a, SUM( puntos_jugador_a ) AS total FROM game
WHERE torneo_organizacion = "MZF-CAB" AND jugador_a = 125
AND fecha_partido >= ( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 365 DAY ) 

SELECT torneo_organizacion, jugador_b, SUM( puntos_jugador_b ) AS total FROM game
WHERE torneo_organizacion = "MZF-CAB" AND jugador_b = 125
AND fecha_partido >= ( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 365 DAY )
```

Comment: Y cual seria el problema?

Comment: El problema es que quiero juntar las dos consultas en una sola y sumar sus resultados,  lo dice en la primera linea.

Comment: Eso no es un problema.. eso es lo que tenes que hacer... cual es el problema que tuviste tratando de hacer eso?

Comment: Es un problema para mi, porque no lo se hacer jeje.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes tener ambos resultados, como jugador A y como jugador B:

```
SELECT
    SUM( IF(jugador_a = 125, puntos_jugador_a, 0) ) AS puntos_jugador_a,
    SUM( IF(jugador_b = 125, puntos_jugador_b, 0) ) AS puntos_jugador_b
FROM game
WHERE
    torneo_organizacion = "MZF-CAB"
    AND 125 IN (jugador_a, jugador_b)
    AND fecha_partido >= ( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 365 DAY );
```

En el `SELECT` tenemos dos sumas, que irán sumando el contenido de `puntos_jugador_a` o `puntos_jugador_b` solo en caso de que el jugador que estemos sumando sea el `a` o el `b` (suma `0` en otro caso).

También puedes obtener los datos totales mediante la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
    SUM( IF(jugador_a = 125, puntos_jugador_a, puntos_jugador_b) ) AS puntos
FROM game
WHERE
    torneo_organizacion = "MZF-CAB"
    AND 125 IN (jugador_a, jugador_b)
    AND fecha_partido >= ( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 365 DAY );
```

En este caso suma los puntos de `puntos_jugador_a` si es el jugador `a` o `puntos_jugador_b` en caso contrario (se asume que será el `b`).

Ambas consultas comparten el mismo `WHERE`:

```
AND 125 IN (jugador_a, jugador_b)
```

En el que se buscan los registros cuyo `jugador_a` o `jugador_b` sea el que estamos analizando.

Puedes ver el funcionamiento en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jvoCkte5qH25uWfWxQgP17/1

Comment: Si quisiera hacer eso mismo para todos los jugadores de la tabla sin usar ids, o sea diciéndole que sume todos los puntos de jugador_a y jugador_b cuando sean iguales y que los agrupe, cómo tendría que hacer ?

Comment: Creo que la consulta es lo suficientemente diferente como para que requiera una pregunta independiente, así no nos salimos del tema de ésta. Cuando la hayas redactado déjame un comentario en esta misma respuesta y la miro.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/482537/problema-formulaci%c3%b3n-query-mysql

Comment: Ahí arme la query como pude pero me da mal, te agradezco tu ayuda de verdad! Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT SUM( puntos_jugador_a + (SELECT SUM( puntos_jugador_b )` `AS total FROM game WHERE torneo_organizacion = "MZF-CAB" AND jugador_b = 125 AND fecha_partido >= ( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 365 DAY ))) AS total FROM game WHERE torneo_organizacion = "MZF-CAB" AND jugador_a = 125 AND fecha_partido >= ( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 365 DAY )`

Esta consulta si está bien, lo único que te dará es la sumatoria de los puntos, que es lo que se entiende quieres obtener. No sé si sea la manera más óptima. Además, sale del código brindado por ti, o sea que si tus consultas estaban funcionando, estas deben funcionar.

Tema que recomiendo estudiar:

SUBCONSULTAS

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGPb5E1UAJA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCpMJ2LFdLg

Comment: Ahí parece más bien que hay que usar un UNION de SQL...

Comment: @Jakala como él habló de unir las dos sumas, pensé era que quería el resultado de ambas. Pero según la respuesta marcada como correcta, parece que quería hacer todo en una sola, incluso mostrando campos.