# Problema formulación query MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla de partidos donde quiero obtener la suma de los puntos de los jugadores, el jugador lo cruzo con la tabla player donde el id es el identificador, en la tabla game el jugador puede aparecer tanto en jugador_a como jugador_b, o sea que cuando hago la suma de los puntos de los jugadores busco el id del jugador en las dos columnas. Me tranque un poco con la query y no logo resolverla, me suma los puntos solo cuando el id corresponde al jugador_a, pero no suma cuando los puntos corresponden al id del jugador_b.

```
SELECT
    (puntos_a + puntos_b) AS puntos,
    id
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        SUM(puntos_jugador_a) AS puntos_a,
        0 AS puntos_b,
        jugador_a AS id
    FROM
        game
    WHERE
        torneo_organizacion = "MZF-CAB"
    GROUP BY
        jugador_a
    UNION ALL
SELECT
    0 AS puntos_a,
    SUM(puntos_jugador_b) AS puntos_b,
    jugador_b AS id
FROM
    game
WHERE
    torneo_organizacion = "MZF-CAB"
GROUP BY
    jugador_b
) t
GROUP BY
    id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que lo más sencillo es hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
    torneo_organizacion,
    jugador,
    SUM( IF( jugador_a = jugador, puntos_jugador_a, puntos_jugador_b ) ) AS puntos
FROM game
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT(jugador_a) jugador
  FROM game
  UNION SELECT DISTINCT(jugador_b) jugador
  FROM game
) jugadores
    ON jugador IN (jugador_a, jugador_b)
GROUP BY torneo_organizacion, jugador;
```

He dividido la consulta en dos: obtener el listado de jugadores y obtener la suma de los puntos.

Para empezar obtengo el listado completo de jugadores mediante la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(jugador_a) jugador
FROM game
UNION SELECT DISTINCT(jugador_b) jugador
FROM game
```

Posteriormente, con ese listado de jugadores, podemos obtener la suma de puntos de manera similar a como te indiqué anteriormente:

```
SUM( IF( jugador_a = jugador, puntos_jugador_a, puntos_jugador_b ) )
```

Suma los puntos de `puntos_jugador_a` si éste es `jugador_a` o, en caso contrario, suma los de `puntos_jugador_b`.

Puedes ver la consulta funcionan en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jnTr6bU4QtgUu6wx49Abhd/0

Comment: Justo lo había resuelto, pero así también me funciono, la probé y funciona perfecto. Gracias!